# Composer archive exclude allowing files in an excluded directory due to force-included file types

Tags: composer-php, gitignore

The archive:exclude rules below are doing everything I want *except* the `.wordpress-org` directory is included (it shouldn't be) because it has force-allowed file types, such as SVG at `.wordpress-org/icon.svg` (along with other force-allowed file types like PNG).

```json
...
"archive": {
    "exclude": [
        "*",
        ".*",
        "*/",
        "!vendor/*",
        "!dist/*",
        "!languages/*",
        "!*.{bmp,csv,gif,jpg,jpeg,pdf,php,png,svg,tiff,txt,webp}",
        "node_modules/"
    ]
},
...
```

So how do I force-include bmp,csv,gif,jpg,etc... file extensions *unless they're in the root dir's `.wordpress-org` directory?

I tried `"!/!(.*/).{bmp,csv,gif,jpg,jpeg,pdf,php,png,svg,tiff,txt,webp}"` (thanks to some researching at https://globster.xyz/), but that didn't do the trick.

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe ".*" means everything that starts with "." is gonna be excluded, ".wordpress-org" falls under that criteria

Comment: Right. It *would be excluded* from that pattern match but gets re-included because of the
`"!*.{bmp,csv,gif,jpg,jpeg,pdf,php,png,svg,tiff,txt,webp}",`
line re-includes it because the exclamation point force-includes images, PDFs, etc. in *all directories even if excluded*